# В объявлении употреблено слово "зад". Как назвать эту речевую ошибку?

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

Как назвать такую речевую ошибку, если в объявлении употребляют слово "зад"? Именно в прямом смысле. Очень грубое слово.

Comment: Не повторяясь, в текст вопроса полезно было б вставить цитатку.

Comment: Контекст нужен. В самом слове зад ошибки нет. "Пропал кобель, 2 года, беспородный, перед рыжий, зад черный. Нашедшему ошибку - вознаграждение.".

Answer (score 4):

Грубым это слово может сделать только контекст, обращающий *прямой* его смысл в переносный. Можно представить себе рекламу недвижимости с упоминанием избушки, которая "повернётся к новому обладателю передом, а к лесу - задом". В портняжном деле употребляется понятие "зад платья" (смысл и здесь прямой: это обо всей задней стороне, без намёков на части тела).

Answer (score 2):

> [ЗАД](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4), -а (-у), предл. о заде, на заду; мн. зады, -ов; м. 1. Часть туловища животных, противоположная голове. Брыкаться задом. Бежать, вскидывая з. 2. Разг.-сниж. Часть тела человека ниже спины; задница. Подложить под з. подушку. Хлопнуть по заду кого-л. Вытолкать в з. Дать под з. коленкой. Убери свой з. (разг.-сниж.; отойди). 3. Разг. Задняя часть чего-л. (обычно автомобиля, повозки и т.п.; противоп.: перёд). Разбить з. автомобиля. Поезд показал нам свой з. (ушел, уехал, исчез вдали). Испачкать з. плаща. 4. только мн.: зады, -ов. Разг. Место за дворами, позади изб; задворки. Идти, пробираться задами. <Задок, -дка; м. (1-3 зн.). Задний (см.).

Как видим, у слова *зад* есть как несколько значений. Если Вы о части тела человека ниже спины, то это значение разговорно-сниженное, неуместное в официальном объявлении. Это вид  **стилистической** ошибки: смешение разностильной лексики, в данном случае — немотивированное использование разговорной лексики.

Comment: Даже не разговорной, а просторечной.        L_I, просторечная лексика допускается в разговорном стиле, но никак не в деловом, а объявление - жанр официально-делового стиля, поэтому эта ошибка и относится к стилистическим.